# Django Query "not in" M2M

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I got these three models:

```py
class Crcheck(models.Model):
   crlist = models.ForeignKey("crlists.Crlist", on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
   persons = models.ForeignKey("persons.Person", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   ...
```

```
| id  | crlist_id  |  persons_id |
| 41  |    2       |     64      |
| 42  |    3       |     64      |
```

```py
class Cuslistprofile(models.Model):
   customer= models.ForeignKey("customers.Customer",on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   crlist = models.ManyToManyField("crlists.Crlist") 
   ...
```

```py
class Crlist(models.Model):
   dbname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   ...
```

As a result of the M2M Django generates this table "**cuslistprofiles_cuslistprofile_crlist**":

```
| id  | cuslistprofile_id  |  crlist_id |
| 9   |    4               |     2      |
| 13  |    4               |     3      |
| 14  |    4               |     5      |
| 19  |    4               |     7      |
```

I want to get all the **crlist** values that are in "**cuslistprofiles_cuslistprofile_crlist**"  but missing in "**crcheck**". In this particular example I want to retrieve **5** and **7**.

How can I achieve that in Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Crlist.objects.filter(cuslistprofile__isnull=False, crcheck=None).distinct()
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

Comment: That did the trick, I just added a few more filters and it worked.